# C# - Load data infile to mysql - fatal error

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, visual-studio, file

I'm trying to load data to a mysql table, when I run the code in the MySql Workbench, it works fine, but when I try to run it in my c# application, I get this error:

```
Fatal error encountered during command execution.
```

Here's my code:

```
mConn.Open(); //Opens the connection
string query = "delete from time; alter table time auto_increment=1; LOAD DATA INFILE 'C://time_u.txt' INTO TABLE `time` CHARACTER SET 'utf8' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (@col2, @col3) set date = @col2, hour = @col3;";
WriteDataToDataBase(query); //This guy just executes the command.ExecuteNonQuery();
mConn.Close();
```

Ps: I have 3 columns, the first one is a primary key (id) which I can't import, it needs to go up by one automatically, the second is the date (varchar) and third is the hours (varchar as well).

**UPDATE** 
I tried to change the LOAD DATA code and I found out that the part that gives the error is this part: `(@col2, @col3) set date = @col2, hour = @col3;`.
When I remove this, the code works (it doesn't work in my case because without this it tries to put data in the Primary key) but it doesn't show that first error.

Thanks...

Comment: Side note: `delete from time; alter table time auto_increment=1;` can be better replaced with `truncate table time`

Comment: @RaymondNijland thanks for your reply, I'll try to use another method to execute. I'll keep you updated if it works.

Comment: i don't believe ExecuteNonQuery() running MySQL client supports multiple statements separated with semicons (`;`)

Comment: @RaymondNijland I tried to execute only the LOAD DATA code but it gave me the same error

Comment: Have you tried to execute your commands step by step? Delete, then alter, then load data ... Next test could be combine delete and alter statements. Still get an error? What Exception is thrown? Stacktrace?

Comment: @nilsK When I run only the delete or the alter (or these two together) it works just fine. When I try to run only the Load Data code, it gives me the same error `Fatal error encoutered during command execution` I tried to break the Load Data code in parts and it seems that this error is thrown in the `(@col2, @col3) set date = @col2, hour = @col3` but I don't know what's wrong in that code (since it works in the workbench)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySql.Data is treating `@col2`, `@col3` as (undefined) query parameters, which is causing this error. One workaround would be to add `AllowUserVariables=true` to your connection string.

The other workaround would be to avoid the variables and just load directly into the columns you want:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C://time_u.txt'
INTO TABLE time
CHARACTER SET 'utf8'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(date, hour);
```

Comment: Finally got it working using your second workaround. Thank you very much!!